# Segmentation error due to allocation issues?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Hi so im preety new to coding and I have recently hit a brickwall

This program has a segmentation fault  debug and I think it has to do with allocating space for the buffer array or the input file , as those kept popping up as solutions in my search for an answer.
If you know what I did wrong I would appreciate if you told me rather than giving me the solution. Also Im completely lost on how to allocate memory to anything , so it would be great if someone explained how to allocate memory in context to the code.

It is supposed to read a file structured like this

```
2
3 4
3 4
```

where 2 = how many files are downloading, 3 = the Kb/s of file( each line represents a file) , and 4 = time remaining until done. The program is supposed to output a file out that has the time needed for all the things to download(mind you when a file finishes the speed goes up to others)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  FILE *in = fopen("download.in", "r");
  FILE *out = fopen("download.out", "w");
  int i, n, j, a, k, o;
  char buffer[100];

  fgets(buffer, 10, in);
  sscanf(buffer, "%d", &n);
  int tn[n];
  int xn[n];

  i = 0;
  while (i < n) {
    fgets(buffer, 100, in);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &tn[i], &xn[i]);
    ++i;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j){
      if (tn[i] > tn[j]){
        a =  tn[i];
        tn[i] = tn[j];
        tn[j] = a;

        a =  xn[i];
        xn[i] = xn[j];
        xn[j] = a;
      }
    }

  }
  i = 1;
  float b ;
  k = 0;
  o = 1;
  while(o < n){
    if(xn[o] == xn[o - 1]){
      k = tn[o] + tn[o - 1]
      ;
    }
    else{
      b = (tn[o] * xn[o]) / (tn[o] + tn[o - 1] + k);
      k = 0;
    }
    ++o;
  }


  fprintf( out, "%f", b  );

  fclose(in); fclose(out);


  return 0;
}
```

I know the answer it gives is not accurate but I want to fix the segmentation fault first then deal with that

gdb r then gdb bt returns this

```
(gdb) r 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                                   
_IO_fgets (buf=0x7fffffffeb30 "", n=10, fp=0x7fffffffeac0) at iofgets.c:50                                             
50      iofgets.c: No such file or directory.                                                                          
(gdb) bt                                                                                                               
#0  _IO_fgets (buf=0x7fffffffeb30 "", n=10, fp=0x7fffffffeac0) at iofgets.c:50                                         
#1  0x0000000000400766 in main () at main.c:11
```

codeblocks says the code is ok and the site I am trying to give this says there is a segmentation fault aswell.

Comment: Do basic error handling - ie, check return value of `fopen`.

Comment: "codeblocks says the code is ok". An IDE cannot tell you that your code is functionally or logically correct. That's not its job. It only tells you that your code can compile.

Comment: `fopen` failed because it coundn't locate the file `download`. that is why is good to check the return value of fopen before using either in or out. Specify the full path for the file `download.out` and `download.out` or if you are using an IDE set the working directory to current directory

Comment: Other issues: `fprintf( out, "%f", b  );` can happen without `b` being assigned.  Do you want integer division with `(tn[o] * xn[o]) / (tn[o] + tn[o - 1] + k);` or floating point division with ?

Comment: Umm ok the download.in is in the same folder , fopen does not return null . Let me also clarify that the .out file is edited and the code runs fine on my pc , but the site that im trying to submit it to detects a segmentation fault.

Comment: -chux 
its an exercise and the file that is given as input will always be formatted as I have shown above , and I am supposed to  be rounded to the closest integer (which I'm in the process of figuring out how to do)

Comment: 'int i, n, j, a, k, o;' didn't go any further :(

Comment: `i = 0;
  while (i < n) {
    fgets(buffer, 100, in);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &tn[i], &xn[i]);
    ++i;
  }` use sane loops. :: `for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
    if(!fgets(buffer, 100, in)) break;
    if(sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &tn[i], &xn[i])< 2) break;
  }`

Comment: -wildplasser WOW thanks , I tried doing it with a for loop at start , but did not succeed

Answer (score 0):

Here is code with segfault fixed. I had to (1) specify absolute path and (2) change the loop to a for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *in = fopen("/home/developer/CLionProjects/untitled4/download.in", "r");
    FILE *out = fopen("/home/developer/CLionProjects/untitled4/download.out", "w");
    int i, n, j, a, k, o;
    char buffer[100];

    fgets(buffer, 10, in);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &n);
    int tn[n];
    int xn[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!fgets(buffer, 100, in)) break;
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %d", &tn[i], &xn[i]) < 2) break;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (tn[i] > tn[j]) {
                a = tn[i];
                tn[i] = tn[j];
                tn[j] = a;

                a = xn[i];
                xn[i] = xn[j];
                xn[j] = a;
            }
        }

    }
    i = 1;
    float b;
    k = 0;
    o = 1;
    while (o < n) {
        if (xn[o] == xn[o - 1]) {
            k = tn[o] + tn[o - 1];
            fprintf(out, "Some number: %d\n", k);
        } else {
            b = (tn[o] * xn[o]) / (tn[o] + tn[o - 1] + k);
            k = 0;
            fprintf(out, "Some number: %d\n", k);
        }
        ++o;
    }

    fclose(in);

    const char *text = "Write this to the file";
    fprintf(out, "Some text: %s\n", text);

    fclose(out);

    int c;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("/home/developer/CLionProjects/untitled4/download.out", "r");
    if (file) {
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
            putchar(c);
        fclose(file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Every Input and Conversion* should be **validated**. How is the error handled if either `fgets(buffer, 10, in);` or `sscanf(buffer, "%d", &n);` fail? What value for `'n'` is then used in `int tn[n];` and `int xn[n];`? Why is `10` used in `fgets(buffer, 10, in);`? Why not `fgets(buffer, sizeof *buffer, in);`? Or, better yet, define a constant, e.g. `#define MAX 100`, `char buffer[MAX] = "";` and then `fgets(buffer, MAX, in);`.